# @media dependant from zoom factor?

Tags: html, css, screen-resolution

I am trying to understand the `@media` in CSS, and it seems that `max-width` has not relation with screen resolution, but the window size itself, here is the code:

```
@media (max-width: 2000px) {
div
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
}
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
div
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:blue;
}
}
```

at zoom 100%:

[image: Zoom 100%]

but, at zoom 150%

[image: zoom 150%]

I tried it on Chrome and Firefox, and the same thing happened.

So what is the right code to control the CSS independent of the zoom factor?

Answer (score 2):

Don't look only at max-width, @media works in different way.
I learned how use it by following this great tutorial with examples:
[[http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/]](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/%5d)